# LaunchUriAsync is working only with debugger connected in PushNotificationTrigger BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, background-task

Currently, we are trying to launch the application from PushNotificationTrigger BackgroundTask using `LaunchUriAsync`, when user accepts VOIP call. `LaunchUriAsync` is only working with the debugger attached, as soon as detached the debugger `LaunchUriAsync` stopped launching the application. After reattaching to the process it starts working again.

```
public sealed class PushNotificationReciever : IBackgroundTask
    {

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            RawNotification notification = (RawNotification)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("custom:\\data"));
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-18362#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) states:

> Unless you are calling this API from a Windows desktop application, this API must be called from within an ASTA thread (also known as the UI thread).

You cannot do this from a background task.

Comment: If that is the case how it is working with the debugger attached.

Comment: Being debugged changes the way the app is run.

Answer (score 0):

`LaunchUriAsync` from a background task works for me with the target version `1803`. Changing to `1809` and higher breaks it.